# How to toggle a class on child objects using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup

```
<div class="question">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <div class="answer">content 1</div>
</div>

<div class="question">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <div class="answer">content 2</div>
</div>

<div class="question">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <div class="answer">content 3</div>
</div>
```

I want to toggle the class "active" when a question div is clicked. I've attempted this following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".question").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");  
        $(this).find("h2").toggleClass("active");   
        $(this).find("answer").toggleClass("active");   
    });
});
</script>
```

But this unfortunately adds the class active to every question,h2 and answer, rather than just the one that was clicked.  I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Shadi

Comment: By any chance do you have another (enclosing) `div` with the class `question`?

Comment: Are you wanting to turn off the class `active` for your second question if your first question is clicked? Or just swap toggle each question independently of the other?

Comment: @K Prime: I'm not sure what you mean, if you mean do i have anything else around them that has the class of question, then no.

Comment: @K Prime: actually you were kind of right, my mark up wasn't as i thought it was i had one question div and all the others inside, i've now fixed it and the code works as above :) sorry for my premature answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it will set whichever is clicked to active:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".question").click(function () {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).find("h2, div.answer").addClass("active");
    });
});
</script>
```

If a question is clicked on twice in a row it will stay active as opposed to toggling off. Or if you're actually looking to have a second click in a row make it inactive:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".question").click(function () {
        var isAlreadyActive = $(this).hasClass("active");
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        if (!isAlreadyActive) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).find("h2, div.answer").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Seems my code didn't work because as highlighted in the comments i actually had an error in my html. But this improved what i did so i'm accepting it :) Cheers.

Comment: @Parrots, thanks a lot, specially for providing an alternative as its exactly what I was looking for.